# Chamar metodo do filho no componente pai dentro de um v-dialog

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, vue.js, vuetify

Olá, estou tentando chamar um método que está no componente filho através do componente pai. O PORÉM é que se eu envolver o componente filho especificamente em um 'v-dialog' o código não funciona, mas se eu colocar qualquer outro elemento como uma 'div' envolvendo o filho, funciona tranquilamente.

Aqui está a forma que funciona:

```
<v-btn @click="teste">CHAMAR METODO DO FILHO</v-btn>

<div>
  <PageTitle ref="form" />
</div>
```

E aqui a que não funciona:

```
<v-btn @click="teste">CHAMAR METODO DO FILHO</v-btn>

<v-dialog>
  <PageTitle ref="form" />
</v-dialog>
```

O exceção gerada é

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined"
```

No componente pai eu tenho isso:

```
methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$refs.form.submit()
    }
  },
```

No componente filho eu tenho isso:

```
methods: {
    submit() {
        ...
    }
  }
```

Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço :D

**SOLUÇÃO**

O problema é que a propriedade `this.$refs` só pode ser acessada depois de renderizar o componente (dica do amigo [Tiago A](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/56013/tiagoa)), logo coloquei meu método para executar na propiedade `update()` que executa algo sempre que o componente é renderizado.

Mais sobre o [update()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated)

Comment: Esse método `submit` foi você que implementou? Se sim, edite a pergunta e inclua o código JS.

Comment: Valeu amigo, acabei de adicionar :D

Comment: No meu teste funcionou, quer complementar seu código? Pode ser que o problema esteja em outra parte do código.

Comment: Com um dialog envolvendo o componente filho?

Comment: Eu coloquei um componente qualquer, não utilizando o vuetify.

Comment: Fiz o teste com o dialog e realmente não funciona. O problema é o seguinte: na documentação do Vue.js diz que o conteúdo de `this.$refs` é preenchido após a renderização, ou seja, se o elemento com a referência não estiver renderizado, não vai estar acessível via `$refs`.

Comment: Tiago, valeu mesmo pela ajuda. Consegui! Fiz o seguinte, já que ele só consegue acessar o `$ref` depois de renderizar o componente, coloquei meu método no `update()` assim toda vez que renderiza ele executa. Obrigado de verdade :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ficar mais claro, vou adicionar a resposta do meu comentário aqui:

O problema é o seguinte: na documentação do [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) diz que o conteúdo de `this.$refs` é preenchido após a renderização, ou seja, se o elemento com a referência não estiver renderizado, não vai estar acessível via `$refs`.